# Plugin install/remove causes fatal error on local

Tags: craft3, plugins, error-message, install, uninstall

After updating to Craft Pro 3.7.44 my local MAMP site now throws a server error when adding/removing a plugin within the Craft CMS UI. Editing the composer.json file manually and running composer update seems to bypass this error.

```
A fatal error has occurred:

Status: Internal Server Error

Response: { "error": "Failed to instantiate component or class \"yii\\shell\\Bootstrap\".", "exception": "yii\\di\\NotInstantiableException", "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php", "line": 509, "trace": 
[{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php", "line": 385, "function": "getDependencies", "class": "yii\\di\\Container", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php", "line": 170, "function": "build", "class": "yii\\di\\Container", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php", "line": 345, "function": "get", "class": "yii\\di\\Container", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php", "line": 292, "function": "createObject", "class": "yii\\BaseYii", "type": "::" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php", "line": 116, "function": "bootstrap", "class": "yii\\base\\Application", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php", "line": 271, "function": "bootstrap", "class": "craft\\web\\Application", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php", "line": 93, "function": "init", "class": "yii\\base\\Application", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php", "line": 109, "function": "init", "class": "craft\\web\\Application", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php", "line": 204, "function": "__construct", "class": "yii\\base\\BaseObject", "type": "->" },
{ "function": "__construct", "class": "yii\\base\\Application", "type": "->" }, { "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php", "line": 419, "function": "newInstanceArgs", "class": "ReflectionClass", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php", "line": 170, "function": "build", "class": "yii\\di\\Container", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php", "line": 365, "function": "get", "class": "yii\\di\\Container", "type": "->" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php", "line": 61, "function": "createObject", "class": "yii\\BaseYii", "type": "::" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php", "line": 247, "function": "createObject", "class": "Craft", "type": "::" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php", "line": 51, "function": "require" },
{ "file": "/Users/user/repos/CRAFT_BOOTSTRAP/web/index.php", "line": 25, "function": "require" }] }
```

```
Craft Pro 3.7.44
PHP - 8.0.8
DB - MySQL 5.7.34

Plugins:

Contact Form 2.5.1
Contact Form Extensions 1.3.2
Control Panel CSS 2.4.0
Empty Coalesce 1.0.6
Neo 2.13.11
Redactor 2.10.8
Table Maker 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that are experiencing the same issue, update your compser.json file to look like this:

```
"config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "craftcms/plugin-installer": true,
            "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true
        },
    }
```

I believe this is only a temporary fix. Further updates can be found on the craft github https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/11399